# Detect special characters keypresses in AutoHotkey

Tags: special-characters, autohotkey

How can I detect a key combination such as AltGr and special characters (I want to detect AltGr + ì, I have an Italian keyboard layout). Looking up online I came across SC combinations, which would be SC236, so I tried

```
<^>!SC236::send ~
```

Comment: Did you try `<^>!ì::`? `<^>!«::` seems to work perfectly for me (Portuguese keyboard layout).

Comment: Try `<^>!vkDD::send ~` (key's virtual key)

Comment: @user3419297 Thanks it worked, could you explain to me how these codes work?

Comment: @D.Pardal I did try but it gave me a syntax error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hotkeys can be triggered by using the hexadecimal **virtual key (VK) code** of a key

```
<^>!vkDD::send ~
```

in the rare case where a key has no name or the standard code doesn't work.

The virtual key code of such a key can be determined by following the steps at [Special Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm#SpecialKeys). (On step 6 note the value in the first column of the list (VK)).